# Adding hyperlinks and text to speaker notes section within PowerPoint using VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to loop through all the slides in a PowerPoint and add the associated text for the links and the full hyperlink to the notes section.

I've been successful in making that happen, but now I get a "Run-time error '-21247188160 (80048240)'. In my research folks have suggested adding a timer/DoEvent to the code within the loop section as it can stumble a bit. That unfortunately didn't work.

Any ideas?

```
Sub AddHyperlinksWithNameToNotes()

   Dim vSlide As Slide
   Dim vHyperlink As Hyperlink
   Dim sLinks As String
   Dim vShape As Shape
   
   
    For Each vSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each vHyperlink In vSlide.Hyperlinks
            sLinks = sLinks _
                & vHyperlink.TextToDisplay _
                & ": " & vHyperlink.Address _
                & vbCrLf
        Next
        vSlide.NotesPage.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange = ""
        vSlide.NotesPage.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = sLinks
        sLinks = ""
    Next
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in the documentation, hyperlinks in PP may be of 2 types: msoHyperlinkRange and msoHyperlinkShape - see https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/vba/api/powerpoint.hyperlink.type. So hyperlink of `msoHyperlinkShape` hasn't TextToDisplay.

Try to check `vHyperlink.Type`:

```
Sub AddHyperlinksWithNameToNotes()

    Dim vSlide As Slide
    Dim vHyperlink As Hyperlink
    Dim sLinks As String
    Dim vShape As Shape
    
    For Each vSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each vHyperlink In vSlide.Hyperlinks
            
            If vHyperlink.Type = msoHyperlinkRange Then ' check type
                ttd = vHyperlink.TextToDisplay
            Else
                ttd = "LinkOnShape"
            End If
            
            sLinks = sLinks _
                & ttd _
                & ": " & vHyperlink.Address _
                & vbCrLf
        Next
        vSlide.NotesPage.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange = ""
        vSlide.NotesPage.Shapes(2).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = sLinks
        sLinks = ""
    Next
End Sub
```